# using entity models in nodejs and angularjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I'm building a node application with angular integrated.

I have implemented a kind of entity class for my data models as follows;

`Student.js`

```
function Student(name, age,gender) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.gender = gender;
}

Student.prototype = {
  namge : '',
  age   : '',
  gender: '',

  getName   : function() { return this.name; },
  getAge    : function() { return this.age; },
  getGender : function() { return this.gender; },

  setName   : function(name)   { this.name = name; },
  setAge    : function(age)    { this.age = age; },
  setGender : function(gender) { this.gender = gender; },

  save      : function() {
    // write changes to database
  }
}
```

I want to also maintain a kind of angular model on the client side that corresponds to the server side entity model above, so that when a given student is requested from the client side, i send an instance of Student which is assigned to an angular model. And i want to also be able to send the angular model to the server side which would then become an instance of Student again.

I don't have much experience with this, but I hope my description is clear enough.
Please do help if you have any suggestions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be doing this over REST with JSON then you probably want to use the $resource service from Angular.

As long as you have a conforming series of endpoints with support for GET/POST/PUT/DELETE it will do the plumbing for you.  At least as far as fetching and saving data.

No matter what you do in the code, however, you are still only ever sending JSON in requests and responses.  So your code on the server has to retrieve the JSON and should most likely perform some sanity checks on it.

Your client-side code wrapped around a $resource can manipulate whatever object you send and then call save() - and the like - to send it back to the server.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/%24resource)

YOu can, of course, do the same thing with $http but that requires a little more work in the transferring of the data.  Where $resource may align with what you are after.